# strange failure using stringstream to read a float value

Tags: c++, c++11, stringstream

I have the following simple code which reads a float value (double) using c++ `stringstream`. I use stringstream::good to detect whether the read is successful. Strangely, the value is read into the float variable, but `good()` returns false. The code at the bottom returns:

```
failed: 3.14159
```

I compiled the code using gcc 4.8.1 under mingw32, with `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp`.

Any idea why this read is not `good`? And what's the proper way to tell that the float is actually read successfully?

Thanks

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void readFloat(string s) {
  double i = 0!; 
  stringstream ss(s); 
  ss >> i;
  if (ss.good())
    cout << "read: " << i << endl;
  else
    cout << "failed: " << i << endl;
}

main() {
  readFloat("3.14159");
}
```

Comment: The read hit the EOF character, thus `eof()` was set.

Comment: I don't believe that g++ allows a `main()` without returntype declaration. What is the real code?

Comment: That is the actual code copy-pasted.

Comment: Oh wow, didn't think GCC would accept that. Still, turn on warnings (-Wall), then it gives `warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘main’ with no type`.

Comment: @TingL Did any of these answers help? If so, you can accept one of them by clicking on the checkmark next to their answer. It expresses to the community that you have found an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When streams reach the end of the stream during an extraction, they set the `std::ios_base::eofbit` in the stream state to alert to the user that no more characters can be read. This means that `good()` no longer returns true until the stream state is cleared.

Generally, `good()` is not a reliable way to determine I/O success. `good()` as a condition means that every bit (including `eofbit`) is not set, which can be misleading if you are simply trying to determine if an I/O operation succeeded. Because `eofbit` is set, your program tell you that your I/O operation failed when it didn't.

Instead, it is better to wrap the entire extraction in a conditional to determine if it succeeds. There will be an implicit cast in the stream to boolean and the stream will call `!this->fail()` internally, which is a better alternative than `good()`:

```
if (ss >> i) {
    std::cout << "read: " << i << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "failed: " << i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Does this mean that the proper way to check if the read is successful (regardless of everything else) is to test `(!ss.fail())`? Any pitfalls there?

Comment: @TingL Nope, that's **not** the proper way (in general): New users often make the mistake of using `while (!o.fail())` or `while (!o.eof())` as the condition for their loop, when it should be `while (*I/O operation*)` instead like I did above. The former checks the stream state *before* doing input, which is incorrect because it can allow you to use the result of a failed extraction. Don't explicitly use `fail()` unless you have to, and in this case you don't.

Comment: Just to clarify, is it still OK to use (!o.fail()) *after* doing the input? In my case, replace o.good() with (!o.fail()). Any potential issues there? I am kind of nervous about mixing the side effect inside a conditional, and want to avoid such style if possible.

Comment: @TingL There's no problem with checking `fail()` directly after doing the input. However, for your `do {} while(!o.fail())` loop, that's still incorrect. Not only does that cause an extra loop, you will still be using the result of a failed extraction (which could cause Undefined Behavior if you're using a more recent compiler). It's more idiomatic to simply do `while (is >> x)`; that's the way streams were designed to be used.

Answer (score 1):

No strange behaviour here

[stringstream::good()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/)

The function returns false if the end of the file as been reached, which is the case.
If you test good before "ss >> i" I do belive it will return true.

A good way to test would be :

```
  double i = 0.0;
  std::stringstream ss(s); 

  if (!ss.good())
    throw std::exception("Stream not good");
  ss >> i;
  if (!ss.eof())
    throw std::exception("Stream not read entirely");
```

Comment: Try that with an empty string as input. ;) Please check `boost::lexical_cast` for a proper approach for that. Also, `exception` doesn't have a ctor taking a string, use `runtime_error` for that.